# How to color specific text using beamer format in Quarto

Tags: beamer, quarto

I am trying to recreate this Beamer document using Quarto:

**Beamer:**

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
\title{test}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Here is a slide}

Here is {\color{ForestGreen}{forestgreen}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Quarto:**

```
---
title: test
format:
  beamer:
    beameroption:
      dvipsnames
---

# Here is a slide
    
Here is {\color{ForestGreen}{forestgreen}}
```

This generates the error: `Package keyval Error: dvipsnames undefined.`

Maybe I misunderstand `beameroption`? How do I pass a class option to Beamer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer options are for things like activating notes etc. See e.g. section "19.3 Specifying Which Notes and Frames Are Shown" of the beamer user guide to see some examples.

To pass options on the xcolor package, you want to use a class option:

```
---
title: test
format:
  beamer:
    classoption:
      - '`xcolor={dvipsnames}`{=latex}' 
---

# Here is a slide
    
Here is {\color{ForestGreen}{forestgreen}}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering about the specific syntax you used. It worked for to just use `- "xcolor=dvipsnames"`. Any potential issue there?

Comment: @RobertMcDonald With the syntax `xcolor={...}` you can pass more than one option to xcolor (in case you later discover that you need more options, e.g. for coloured tables etc.)

Comment: Also wondering about the `{=latex}` part.

Comment: @RobertMcDonald That's because rmarkdown is a very stupid language and without it, I ended with `xcolor=\{dvipsnames\}` in the latex code which would then of course crash the compilation. Things are so much easier if one  could directly solve the problem in latex instead of having to fight with rmarkdown...

Comment: FYI I've posted an issue about this on github. I don't know if this is a pandoc or quarto issue but I thought it worth reporting:  https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/5493